# When we send transaction to a network we only send the signature of the transaction then how is the miner able to decrypt the message?

Tags: transactions, mining, signature, network

When we send transaction to a network as shown below we only send the signature of the transaction then how is the miner able to decrypt the message?
If only the signed transaction is sent to the network how will the miner be able to decrypt the content of the transaction? Is there anything that is sent along with the signed transaction like the original transaction object? I understand that the unencrypted message should also be sent along with the signed transaction but the send block only takes signature as an argument. Would be thankful if someone could explain me.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhwSGYRmkEU&list=PLJz1HruEnenCXH7KW7wBCEBnBLOVkiqIi&index=4&ab_channel=AustinGriffith
[image: eth.build]

Answer (score 1):

When we send a transaction to the network we send the transaction and the signature.

The miner/validator will verify the transaction is valid and signed and then process the transaction.